# how to handle properties key in CListCtrl?

Tags: mfc, keyboard, clistctrl

I want to handle the properties key press in CListCtrl in MFC and show a context menu which is already shown with right clicking. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by property keys?

Comment: properties key, the shortcut for SHIFT-F10 key, located near WinKey.

Answer (score 0):

The "properties" key is the "Menu" key.
If you already implemented a context menu then the CListCtrl control must have the focus when you press the "properties" key.

Or alternatively, the main window can watch key messages and notify the control.